# mysql fetch to a multidimensional associative arrays php

Tags: php, mysql, associative-array

I have a sql query which returns a bunch of rows containing id,field1,field2,field3 and I want to create an array to be accessed this way:

```
$array[$id]['field1']
```

I tried this:

```
$stmt2->bind_result($idOpcion,$field1,$field2,$field3);
while ($stmt2->fetch()) {

            $options = array(
                "$id" => array(
                    "field1" => $field1,
                    "field2" => $field2,
                    "field2" => $field3)
                );
}
```

and to access:

```
$id = 501; //Just for clarify the example

<option <?php if $options[$id]['field1']==$dimension->getIdDimension()){echo "selected";}?>
value="<?=$dimension->getIdDimension()?>">
<?=$dimension->getNombreDimension()?></option>
```

And I get the message:

```
NOTICE: Undefined offset: 501
```

What I'm doing bad?

As you can imagine, the main goal is to load/select the proper option in a select, based on the stored data. Any other solution?.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$options[$id] = array();`  this would do the job for you.

Comment: check ; missing while setting id in variable

Comment: Typo in  `$options[$id['field1']` - should be `$options[$id]['field1']`. Also the round bracket "(" after "if" is missing

Comment: `$id = 501` missing semi-colon.  `if $options[$id['field1']` missing closing bracket around `$id`

Comment: Thak you for the typos, are ok in my code so the problem is not there. I will try Arsh solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Arsh Singh, now it works!

```
while ($stmt2->fetch()) {

            $options[$id] = array( "field1" => $field1,
                    "field2" => $field2,
                    "field3" => $field3);

}
```